# How do I disambiguate an OSC addresses from regular division by a value in ANTLR4?

Tags: antlr4

I have a grammar where I recently added  syntax for a constant OSC address --- it looks like this

```
OSCAddressConstant: ('/' ('A' .. 'Z' | 'a' .. 'z' | '0' .. '9' | '_')+)+;
```

Typical examples might be

```
/a/b/c
/Handle/SetValue
/1/Volume/Page3
```

Unfortunately, I discovered rather quickly that simple expressions with division: e.g.

```
   foo = 20/10
```

now fail with type errors because the parser thinks that the **/10** is an OSC address and so we get "integer" "Divide" "OSCAddressConstant"

What is the recommended (and hopefully) simplest way to disambiguate these other than changing the actual syntax of the OSC address, which would be a pity.

Thanks in advance

(NB - I saw a similar question about ambiguity between division and regular expression syntax but I did not understand the solution - there was a reference to the use of @member but it was unclear what to do with it - I've not seen that before and other questions about @member seem to have gone unanswered)

Comment: More information about the language is needed. Could you explain when a OSCAddressConstant can occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `OSCAddressConstant` rule is rather a higher level rule, like a complex identifier, possibly qualified. Such higher level constructs should go into the parser, not the lexer.

Just like you would define a qualified identifier as:

```
ID: [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*;
DOT: '.';

qualified: ID (DOT ID)?;
```

you can define your OSC address as:

```
EID: [a-zA-Z0-9_]+;
DIV: '/';

oscAddressConstant: (DIV EID)+;
```

The only drawback with this approach is: when you usually ignore whitespaces this syntax will allow constructs like: `/  abc  / 12`. But if that's something you do not want handle whitespaces in the semantic phase and throw an error then.

Comment: That is a VERY good point that I had not considered --- let me try it and thanks so much for your fast response.

Comment: thank you so much - that completely solved the problem and I'm actually rather annoyed that I didn't figure that one out myself.